# Remove Parameters after Search term

Tags: javascript, parameters

I have a search module that isn't working because it adds parameters to the URL.

For instance this URL works....
https://dev.berry.com/?s=pineapple

but the URL that is given is...
https://dev.berry.com/?s=pineapple**&et_pb_searchform_submit=et_search_proccess&et_pb_include_posts=yes&et_pb_include_pages=yes**

is there javascript that will eliminate from the "&" onward? That way whatever the search term is (pineapple, Tokyo, sunshine) it will work.

Answer (score 0):

> To begin, there should be no error with passing multiple parameters, so if you can, check the backend to fix this error rather than relying on front-end validation

That being said, you might want to checkout the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) module.

```js
const url = new URL("https://dev.berry.com/?s=pineapple**&et_pb_searchform_submit=et_search_proccess&et_pb_include_posts=yes&et_pb_include_pages=yes**");
const search = url.searchParams.get("s");

url.search = "?s=" + search;
console.log(url.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you Elias! So I'd just run this as a script on the basic search landing page?

Comment: This is just a snippet that you can use just before you call the API, also as a function: `function isolateSearch(href){const url = new URL(href);
const search = url.searchParams.get("s");

url.search = "?s=" + search;
return url.toString;}`